# Use Textwriter to write URLs from ComboBox

Tags: c#, file, combobox, outlook, save

I'm currently trying to write URLs that are entered into a `ComboBox` (from an Outlook Addin) into a txt file, but as i beginner i don't really know how to go for it.

I don't have any code snippets that could assist you in anyway so i think I'll just keep it simple, by asking you for the General Approach that I could use in this matter.
All of your help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Add combo items to a `List` and write them to a file using `File`

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
foreach (var text in comboBox1.Items)
{
     lst.Add((string)text);
}
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\file.txt", lst.ToArray());
```

Using `TextWriter`

```
 using (TextWriter TW = new StreamWriter(@"c:\file.txt", true))
            {
                foreach (var text in comboBox1.Items)
                {
                    TW.WriteLine();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
string path=@"C:\Hello.txt";
TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(path,true);

    //Writing selected item of combobox to the file.
    tsw.WriteLine(comboBox1.Items[this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString());


    //Close the file.
    tsw.Close();
```